# Concatenate string through for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to concatenate strings via `for loop` but i'm receiving `NaNs`. What i want to achieve is to get one concatenated string `Div #0, Div #1, Div #2, Div #3,`.

```js
var divLength = $('div').length;

var str = '';
for(var i=0; i<divLength; i++){
  var str =+ "Div #" + [i] + ", ";
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't declare a new `str` variable inside the loop with `var str`. Reuse the one you declare outside the loop. Also do `+=`

```js
var divLength = $('div').length;

var str = '';
for(var i = 0; i < divLength; i++) {
  str += "Div #" + i + ", ";
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Bah, silly me. I guess 3am aint the best time to see such small things x).

Comment: I've never seen that `[i]` wasn't a syntax error, but still, it can just be `i`.

Comment: Right! When you do `"" + [i]` the array is converted to a comma separated string of it's elements. And in the case of `[i]`, an array of one element, lets say that `i = 1` that would be `"1"`. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: @RedMercury Oh, of course. Somehow `[i]` looks so much like an index accessor that I couldn't see the array.

Answer (score 9):

Besides the selected answer, you could do this with a `forEach` if you have a list of stuff to put inside those `divs`:

```
let string = '';
items.forEach(item => string += '<div>'+ item.description + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Typescript ESLint](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/prefer-for-of/#:%7E:text=Enforce%20the%20use%20of%20for,array%20that%20is%20being%20iterated.) recommendations,

> For cases where the index is only used to read from the array being iterated, a for-of loop is easier to read and write.

We can use for-of using the `keys` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys).

```js
let str = ''
for (const i of Array(divLength).keys()) {
  str += `Div #${i}, `;
}
console.log(str);
```

But that has the problem of the trailing comma. We can let JavaScript take care of that using the `join` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const arr = Array.from(Array(divLength).keys()); // [ 0, 1, 2];
const divArray = arr.map(n => `Div #${n}`)       // ['Div #0', 'Div #1', 'Div #2']
const str = divArray.join(', ');                 // 'Div #0, Div #1, Div #2'
```

which can be wrapped up as a one-liner,

```js
const s = Array.from(Array(divLength).keys()).map(val => `Div #${val}`).join(', ')
```

A somewhat less verbose one-liner can be done using `fill` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const s = Array(divLength).fill().map((_, i) => `Div #${i}`).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are concatenating the string for an array then you can do like this. For loop is also best solution but it becomes vast process:

```js
if(this.questionData.length > 0) {
    this.questionData.forEach(questions => {this.questionsParams += '&question'+ questions.question +'=' + questions.value;
    });
}
```

Perfect solution output like this :
`&question1=1&question2=0&question3=1&question4=0`

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = ''
for (let i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
   str += `${arr[i]}`
}
```

This worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var divLength = $('div').length;

var str = '';
for (var i=0; i<divLength; i++) {
  var str += `Div # ${i} , `;
  console.log(str);
}
```

Should work jus fine. You have to add `${i}` to the string inside or it will give u `NaN`