# How to generate HTML text with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of expenses, I want to create a html code to iterate over all the expenses and show their name. I am not working with the DOM,  I literally want to save the html code in a variable, so I can generate a pdf file with it.

This is what I tried:
lets say I have this array

```
const spents = [{expenseName: "Pizza"},{expenseName: "Home"}]

    const testHtml = () => {
         for(let i of spents) {
            const title = `<h1>${i.expenseName}</h1>`
          }
        }
        testHtml()
```

This is the result I want, something like:

> htmlResult =  "`<h1>${i.expenseName}</h1> <h1>${i.expenseName}</h1>`"

by the way, This is for a react native app.

Comment: you can for one use string concatenation (you can use `+=` operator). the other way i could think off, is just having `append` in the loop against the dom directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate string through for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584129/concatenate-string-through-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

```
const spents = [{expenseName: "Pizza"},{expenseName: "Home"}]

const testHtml = () => {
   let title = '';
   for(let i of spents) {
       title += `<h1>${i.expenseName}</h1>`
   }
   return title;
}
testHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const spents = [{
  expenseName: "Pizza"
}, {
  expenseName: "Home"
}];

const result = spents.reduce((prev, curr, index) => index === 0 ? curr.expenseName : `<h1>${prev}</h1> <h1>${curr.expenseName}</h1>`, '');

document.body.append(result);
```